# Can I delete an empty EF Migration safely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've just reviewed a colleague's work and there is an empty EF migration in his PR (up and down methods contain no code). There is another migration after this with DB modifications.

I believe that this empty migration can be deleted on the basis that it does absolutely nothing. There should be a corresponding entry in the _MigrationHistory table, which can also be deleted safely, in my opinion.

My colleagues believe that it should be left in there "just in case".

Are there any EF experts who can say which approach is best, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Тhe truth is somewhere in the middle. You can delete it, but do not delete the migration file directly.

-> Removing A Migration

The following command removes a migration:

```
[Command Line]
dotnet ef migrations remove
[Package Manager Console]
remove-migration
```

You will use this command to remove the latest migration. This will remove the class file that was generated for the latest migration and it will also revert the ModelSnapshot file back to the state of the previous migration. If there are no pending migrations, an exception will be raised. If you want to remove a migration that has been committed, you must reverse the migration first (see below).

You should always use commands to remove a migration instead of simply deleting the migration code file, otherwise the snapshot and migrations will fall out of sync with eachother. Then future migrations will be based on a model that is incorrect. Nevertheless, the remove command will recognise if migration files have been deleted and will revert the snapshot accordingly.

If you need to remove a migration that was generated before the most recent one, you must remove all sunsequent migrations first, then adjust the model and then create a new migration to cater for the changes.

Sores: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations